# FFmpeg retrieve a specific program from TS file

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, mpeg2-ts

I tried to retrieve a specific program from a TS file. 
Said:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'DVB_T_good.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:48.04, start: 55045.888000, bitrate: 14521 kb/s
  Program 300 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��}�TS�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:0[0xbb9]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xbba]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0xbbb]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Program 301 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��N��?S�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:3[0xbc3]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:9[0xbc4]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:10[0xbc5]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Program 302 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��e��^S�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:5[0xbcd]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:6[0xbce]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Program 304 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��S�pcS�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:4[0xbe1]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:7[0xbe2]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:8[0xbe3]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
```

Then I tried to retrieve a specific program as:

**ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0:p:1344 OUTPUT**

It succeeds greatly but the only thing I noticed is:

***it seems to apply transcode (decode & encode again) to the output implicitely?***

```
ffmpeg version N-85693-g8de3458 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/john/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/john/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/john/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/john/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --disable-libopus
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 87.100 /  6. 87.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[NULL @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[NULL @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x33eb3a0] no frame!
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ea200] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x33ec540] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x33b7680] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpegts @ 0x33af360] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 9 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'DVB_T_good.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:48.04, start: 55045.888000, bitrate: 14521 kb/s
  Program 300 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��}�TS�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:0[0xbb9]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xbba]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0xbbb]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Program 301 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��N��?S�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:3[0xbc3]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:9[0xbc4]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:10[0xbc5]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Program 302 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��e��^S�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:5[0xbcd]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:6[0xbce]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Program 304 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?l?��S�pcS�
      service_provider: ?l?��
    Stream #0:4[0xbe1]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:7[0xbe2]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:8[0xbe3]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
map 0:p:304
File '304_1800.ts' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:1 (aac_latm (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:8 -> #0:2 (aac_latm (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] Missing reference picture, default is 65784
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] Missing reference picture, default is 65785
Output #0, mpegts, to '304_1800.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93.100 mp2
    Stream #0:2: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93.100 mp2
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] mmco: unref short failureime=00:00:44.34 bitrate=3506.2kbits/s speed=1.43x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[mpegts @ 0x33af360] PES packet size mismatch
[aac_latm @ 0x3587360] Number of bands (59) exceeds limit (45).
Error while decoding stream #0:7: Invalid data found when processing input
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] mmco: unref short failureime=00:00:45.05 bitrate=3491.2kbits/s speed=1.43x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[mpegts @ 0x33af360] PES packet size mismatchme=00:00:47.74 bitrate=3470.1kbits/s speed=1.43x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x33d6d20] error while decoding MB 97 35, bytestream -12
Error while decoding stream #0:7: Invalid data found when processing input
Error while decoding stream #0:8: Invalid data found when processing input
frame= 1404 fps= 42 q=31.0 Lsize=   20396kB time=00:00:47.88 bitrate=3489.5kbits/s speed=1.42x    
video:14144kB audio:4429kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.813825%
```

You could notice by following message:

**

```
Output #0, mpegts, to '304_1800.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93.100 mp2
    Stream #0:2: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.93.100 mp2
```

**

**If so, could I avoid the transcoding by command? Or it is a necessary? 
It it is a need, WHY?**

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg, by default, will transcode to the default codecs for the output container. Add `-codec copy` or `-c copy` i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -map 0:p:1344 OUTPUT
```